# MasterPDFEditor use black theme for PDF pages

Tags: pdf, openbox

@Crunchbang/Debian x32

I've been using MasterPDFEditor for quite some time & I'm impressed by its PDF annotation capabilities.

However I decided to start using a black GTK+ theme & after that I cannot use this application, simply because it started using black backgrounds for all of my PDF files, while `evince` works nicely.

Is there something I can do about it?

*`evince`*

[image: using evince]

*`MasterPDFEditor`*

[image: using MPE]

Comment: Take a look at the output from `xwininfo`. After running this app you'll need to click on the MPE GUI to get the particulars about this window.

Comment: ok how do I troubleshoot my problem after getting info?

Comment: I was thinking I'd look at the differences b/w MPE using 2 different themes and then see if what changed shows up there. I'm suspecting that you can either control this behavior directly through MPE or through your XResources (`$HOME/.Xresources`) file.